# Discord.js V13 sending message attachments

Tags: javascript, discord.js

After upgrading to discord.js v13 and using `Array.from(message.attachments.values())` instead of `message.attachments.array()` to send attachments from a message,

```js
message.client.channels.cache.get("123456789").send({
    files: [Array.from(message.attachments.values())],
    content: `test`
});
```

I get an error from the console from the node module:

```
Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:223
      if (thing.path) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

The part where the error comes is here:

```js
const findName = thing => {
      if (typeof thing === 'string') {
        return Util.basename(thing);
      }

      if (thing.path) {
        return Util.basename(thing.path);
      }

      return 'file.jpg';
    };
```

I'm really confused on what's wrong or how to fix it, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array inside of an array, remove the extra square brackets. [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) returns a new instance of an `Array` already.

```js
message.client.channels.cache.get("channel id").send({
    files: Array.from(message.attachments.values()),
    content: `test`
});
```

Alternatively you could spread the iterable into an array using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
message.client.channels.cache.get("channel id").send({
    files: [...message.attachments.values()],
    content: `test`
});
```