# Discord.js v13 Sending a File Attachment via URL

Tags: file, url, discord, discord.js, attachment

Discord.js released v13 and I'm trying to update my little homebrew discordbot.

I've come across an issue where I can no longer send an attached file (png) via a web URL.

Discord.js v12

```js
var testchart = `http://jegin.net/testchart2.php?sysid=268.png`;
message.channel.send("Last updated " + updatedAt.fromNow(), {
             files: [{
                attachment: testchart,
                name: 'file.png'
                }]
```

No errors to the console are made (other than a depreciation warning):
[image: No errors to the console are made]

And the bot does not return an image:

[image: no image]

I've tried:

```js
message.channel.send("Last updated " + updatedAt.fromNow(), {
             files: [testchart]
```

and

```js
message.channel.send("Last updated " + updatedAt.fromNow(), {
             files: Array.from(testchart)
        });
```

And finally

```js
message.channel.send({
             files: [testchart],
             content: `Last updated ${updatedAt.fromNow()}`
        });
```

Which gives me this AWFUL output:
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Discord.js's guide for updates: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc

Only other issue I was able to find on the matter: [Discord.js V13 sending message attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790494/discord-js-v13-sending-message-attachments)

Comment: At the bottom left you can see it says `testchart2.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue, it has to do with the **testchart2.php** part of the URL (http://jegin.net/testchart2.php?sysid=268.png)

Was able to get it sent by using:

```js
message.channel.send({
    files: [{
        attachment: testchart,
        name: 'chart.png'
    }],
    content:`Last updated ${updatedAt.fromNow()}`,
});
```

Basically, just take the content part of the v12 and move it to it's own area. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt was close, but not exactly correct. You just have to merge those together (sending messages only takes 1 argument now) and you will get a png file (because you specified the file name), along with the content:

```js
var testchart = `http://jegin.net/testchart2.php?sysid=268.png`;
message.channel.send({
  content: "Last updated " + updatedAt.fromNow(),
  files: [{
    attachment: testchart,
    name: 'file.png'
  }]
})
```